# cannot borrow `*obj` as mutable more than once at a time

Tags: rust

I'm trying to walk a JSON object before further processing. The following code:

```
use serde_json::{json, Map, Value, Result};


fn hex2value(_hex: &Value) -> Result<Value> {
    Ok(Value::from("converted"))
}

fn walk_object(obj: &mut Map<String, Value>) -> Result<()> {
    for (k, v) in obj.iter_mut() {
        if v.is_object() {
            walk_object(v.as_object_mut().unwrap())?
        } else if v.is_string() {
            obj[k] = hex2value(v)?
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    let mut data = json!({
        "name": "John Doe",
        "age": 43,
        "phones": {
            "home": "+44 1234567",
            "work": "+44 2345678"
        }
    });
    walk_object(&mut data.as_object().unwrap());
}
```

falls over with the following error:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*obj` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:13:13
   |
9  |     for (k, v) in obj.iter_mut() {
   |                   --------------
   |                   |
   |                   first mutable borrow occurs here
   |                   first borrow later used here
...
13 |             obj[k] = hex2value(v)?
   |             ^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
```

How can I change the code to satisfy the compiler?

Comment: `let new_value = hex2value(v)?; *v = new_value;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply assign it to `v`. This makes `k` unused, so you can use `values_mut` to iterate over only the values.

```rs
for v in obj.values_mut() {
    if v.is_object() {
        walk_object(v.as_object_mut().unwrap())?;
    } else if v.is_string() {
        *v = hex2value(v)?;
    }
}
```

Given the usage, it would be better if `hex2value` took a `String`, so that you don't have to check again inside `hex2value` if the `Value` is a `String`.

```rs
fn hex2value(_hex: &mut String) -> Result<Value> {
    Ok(Value::from("converted"))
}

if v.is_object() {
    walk_object(v.as_object_mut().unwrap())?;
} else if let Value::String(s) = v {
    *v = hex2value(s)?;
}
```

This also lets you reuse the `String` buffer if you need to, although this probably isn't necessary if you're returning a non-string `Value`.

Since you will always overwrite `v`, you can also use [`take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.take.html) to get an owned `String`. This replaces the `String` in `v` with an empty string while `hex2value` operates on the real `String`.

```rs
fn hex2value(_hex: String) -> Result<Value> {
    Ok(Value::from("converted"))
}

if v.is_object() {
    walk_object(v.as_object_mut().unwrap())?;
} else if let Value::String(s) = v {
    *v = hex2value(std::mem::take(s))?;
}
```

This is useful if you're doing more complex stuff, like putting the `String` somewhere into the generated `Value`. For example, you can now write `hex2value` to reuse the `String`, which avoids an allocation in `Value::from`.

```rs
fn hex2value(mut hex: String) -> Result<Value> {
    hex.clear();
    hex.push_str("converted");
    Ok(Value::from(hex))
}
```

Note that `take` is commonly also a method, like [`Value::take`](https://docs.rs/serde_json/latest/serde_json/value/enum.Value.html#method.take) and [`Option::take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.take). It's most useful when you want an owned value from an `&mut` reference, but also works well as a way to avoid borrow checker issues.

Comment: While I understand your desire for optimization, I think this rarely really makes a measurable difference. So to me, the proper guidance would be to use either `String` or `&str`. I find `&mut String` to be a very odd choice.

Comment: The problem I have with answers that go that far beyond what was actually asked is that it makes the impression to new Rust programmers that all those things **have** to be done. Whilst in 99.9% of cases, your first 10 lines of guidance would be sufficient and less confusing for them. The hint that he shouldn't use `Value` as an input for the function is great (because it has to be checked yet again inside of the function), but the entire section about performance optimization falls very strongly into the category of premature optimization for me.

Comment: Thanks for the very thorough explanation.